# How to save javascript varibles after a user refreshs or closes site

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple clicker game and have an HTML file and a js file. I want to save the varibles in the js file so that when the user refreshs or closes the game, when they open it again their progress is saved. I am using github sites to host the game.
Here's the code: https://github.com/thebearslicer/testIdle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using localStorage.

```
//saving
localStorage.setItem('myItem', 'My value');

//retrieving
const Item = localStorage.getItem('myItem');
```

Comment: Just curious, where does the data go?

Comment: @TheBearSlice It is stored in the browser. Go to developer tools->Application->Local Storage->websiteName to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies, local storage or session storage to make data persistent.
[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Browser storages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) like `window.localStorage` or `window.sessionStorage`. They both fall into cookies for policy laws.